# Coldfusion and Pagination

Tags: search, coldfusion, pagination

First I am very new to ColdFusion, but am learning pretty quickly. So I am trying to build a large database that originally displays all results with 25 lines per page and have a next/prev link to navigate through the pages.

That all works fine, but when I perform a search, and when the new results display of about a couple of pages worth, the pagination links don't work.  When I click on the "next" link it goes back to the original all records display.  How can I fix this or what do I need to do to make it work?

Sorry I'm new at posting and this is my first one.  Hope this is better.

My pagination code...

```
<cfset Next = StartRow + DisplayRows>
<cfset Previous = StartRow - DisplayRows> 

<cfoutput> 
  <cfif Previous GTE 1> 
    <a href="#CGI.Script_Name#?StartRow=#Previous#"><b>Previous #DisplayRows# Records</b></a> 
  <cfelse> 
    Previous Records 
  </cfif> 
  <b> | </b> 
  <cfif Next lte records.RecordCount> 
    <a href="#CGI.Script_Name#?StartRow=#Next#"><b>Next 
    <cfif (records.RecordCount - Next) lt DisplayRows> 
      #Evalute((records.RecordCount - Next)+1)# 
    <cfelse> 
      #DisplayRows# 
    </cfif>Records</b></a>
  <cfelse> Next Records 
  </cfif> 
<cfoutput>
```

My code at the top...

```
<cfparam name="StartRow" default="1"> 
<cfparam name="DisplayRows" default="25"> 

<cfset ToRow = StartRow + (DisplayRows - 1)> 
<cfif ToRow gt records.RecordCount> 
  <cfset ToRow = records.RecordCount> 
</cfif>
```

Let me know if you need to see more...thank you.

Comment: You need to post some code. Not the whole script, just the parts relevant to pagination.

Comment: You don't need evaluate() - #(records.recordcount - next)+1# will output just fine.

Comment: I would change up your page param to be `PageNumber` rather than `StartRow`, it makes sense from a users perspective to link to pagenumbers rather than startrows.

Comment: As an aside, you should look into paginating in the db, rather than in CF. The disadvantage of the latter method is that pulls back all records, even if you only display 25 of them. So as the table grows in size, it will get slower. Paginating in the db only retrieves the records you need, so it is more scalable. You did not mention which dbms you are using, but do a search on: {your DBMS type} pagination.

Comment: Nice question... +1 pagination is always an interesting subject.

Comment: *build a large database* Since no one else has noted this, let me reiterate ;-) If you anticipate having a large number of records to display, you should definitely move the pagination logic to the db. While the current method is a good learning exercise, it will NOT scale well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example I whipped up (sorry if it is terse), and it covers things you already discussed with Mark.  I also like Mark's `<cfloop>` examples above (below). Lol...Where ever this response ends up.

**So we have:**

- query recordcount (max)
- starting in your range
- ending in your range
- output per page

With bonus pageNum querystring for your next grouping of records (which I think is something you would like).

**Then it can look like this in your page:**

```
<cfparam name="pageNum" default="1">

<cfquery name="q" datasource="#application.dsn#">
    select * from yourTable 
</cfquery>

<cfset maxRows = 10>
<cfset startRow = min( ( pageNum-1 ) * maxRows+1, max( q.recordCount,1 ) )>
<cfset endRow = min( startRow + maxRows-1, q.recordCount )>
<cfset totalPages = ceiling( q.recordCount/maxRows )>

<cfset loopercount = round( q.recordCount/10 )>

<cfoutput>
    <cfloop from="1" to="#looperCount#" index="i">
            <a href="?pageNum=#i#">#i#</a>
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput> 

<br><br>

<cfoutput
    query="q" 
    startrow="#startRow#"
    maxrows="#maxRows#">

    #id#<br>

</cfoutput>
```

Comment: thanks for this code...it's a nice setup and is something I can definitely work with. :)

Comment: @CatherineL You are welcome! I figured having a simplified/complete package would be useful :) Edit...Also if this solved your particular problem click that sweet green check box for me!

Comment: I would click on the green check but this didn't really solve my problem.  It still resets to all results when I click on the next page or number.  I'm still figuring out how to do that part.

Comment: @CatherineL It has to do with your query and a few parameters you are missing but must pass from page to page.  I'll alter my answer and see if I can make it clear for you. :)

Comment: @CatherineL ok...I was spending more time on this than I could justify for one question.  I am leaving this as my answer.  I think you should as a new question on pagination persistence (in place) on forms to query filtering of your data (like dropdown select filtering).  Because that is really specific. I'll jump in with the rest of the pack but I want to leave this answer un-altered because it is good as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show how you are actually navigating in your code - that's where the secret sauce is buried. You have everything else you need (maybe more than you need).

You probably have a cfoutput or cfloop in your code somewhere. You would use your *startrow* and *displayrows* to output a set number of rows from the records - like so:

```
<Cfoutput query="records" startrow="#next#" maxrows="#displayrows#">

... code to output your data goes here

</cfoutput>
```

If you are using cfloop it is similar.

```
<Cfloop query="records" startrow="#next#" endrow="#next+displayrows#">

...code to output your data. 

</cfloop>
```

You can also use an index loop like so:

```
<cfloop from="#next#" to="#next+displayrows#" index="x">

.... your outputs will look like this: 
#records[columname][x]#

</cfoutput>
```

HOpefully one of those samples will ring a bell. The logic you put in your code snippets is only creating a starting point and defining how many loops. It's the output that teases out the records to display.

Also note the comment - you almost *never* need `evaluate()` in your code.

Comment: The way I have it now is setup like the first one you listed. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Rereading your question Catherine, it seems like perhaps you are not passing along the search parameters. Eeach link to each new page will need to rerun the _search query_ - and therefore you will need to make sure you include the search variables on the pagination links. Perhaps that's your issue?

Comment: Okay I was thinking that too but not sure how to do that part...is there a easy way/example of how to do that? Or can you direct me to where I can find out how to do it?

Comment: Catherine, not really - now you are asking us to program _for_ you :)  Usually your URL will look something like ?startrow=#next#&searchterm=#form.searchterm#. Then in your query you may have to check to see if you have a FORM element _or_ a URL element to work with. If you don't have either you run your base (get all) query. If you have a search term in the form or url scope you run a search. There is _a lot_ more to it than that, but that's what programming _is_. :)

Comment: Thank you for your help :).  It's at least heading me in the right direction to try and get this thing fixed. :)

Comment: also would it help if I mentioned the search form is based off of 4 or 5 drop down selections.

Answer (score -1):

I worked this out using a cfform tag with BACK - MORE - HOME submit buttons.

The first page had the query for ID 1 to 25 and a MORE submit button.
hidden field was the count 25

The next page had HOME and MORE buttons 
Home had a hidden field of 1
More had a hidden field of count + 25 (50)

The next page had BACK HOME and MORE buttons
Back had hidden field of count - 25
HOME had a hidden field of 1
MORE had a hidden field of count + 25 (75)

and so on.

Query used the number of the hidden field depending on the value of the SUBMIT button to create the query WHERE and output the 25 rows

```
 <cfif submit IS "NEXT">

   <cfset count1 = #count# + 1>
   <cfset count2 = #count# + 25>

 <cfelseif submit is "BACK">

   <cfset count1 = #count# - 26>
   <cfset count2 = #count#>

 <cfelseif submit is "HOME">

   <cfset count1 = 1>
   <cfset count2 = 25>

 </cfif>
```

In query

```
 SELECT *
 FROM mytabl
 WHERE ID BETWEEN #count1# AND #count2#
```

The display

```
 <table>
   <cfoutput query="myquery">
     <tr>
       <td>
         #my data1#
       </td>
       <td>
         #my data2#
       </td>
    </cfoutput>
     </tr>
  <table>
```

Comment: Do not assume id's are contiguous, because the pagination logic breaks if records are deleted. The code may display too few records or possibly none at all. Also, always use `cfqueryparam`. It uses bind variables to protect against sql injection and improve performance.

Comment: I don't know why I get docked for trying to be helpful. That being the case, you're querry could be for the 1st 25 records and your hidden could be the last ID... I was just trying to give CatherineL a starting point...

Comment: I down voted this because it is incorrect and will not work reliably. Plus the sql exposes the database to sql injection. The hidden field approach suffers from the same logic problem. ID value != record number. While help is always appreciated, it important to provide accurate information. Especially to those new to the language.

Comment: Hi Leigh, What I showed was basic structure and it has been working flawlessly for years for one of the sites I built. Looking at CatherineL's script I believed she would know how to edit it and make it work both within her framework and securely. It is simple, fast and keeps info out of the url (form). It seems another way of doing something is always good to know.

Comment: Andy, just because code does not throw a *hard* error, does not mean it works correctly ;-) Look at the sql logic. Think what would happen if there are gaps in the ID's. You might get three records, ten records or none at all. Try it. Whereas the other two answers will work regardless. For queries, *always* use cfqueryparam with variable values. Then queries are protected - even against accidental variable exposure. Plus, bind variables improve performance by promoting re-use of execution plans. There are a few other issues, like lack of scoping and excess # signs, but those are less critical.

Comment: *keeps info out of the url (form)* Not quite. You are storing the count in hidden form field. Then using the raw value from the client in one of the conditions. So unless you are using cfqueryparam in your actual code, that query is vulnerable to sql injection.