# Pagination Persistence (in place) with Form

Tags: forms, coldfusion, pagination

I am trying to figure out how to get pagination to work after filtering a query with a form.  I have setup a page where it's set to show all results and then a form of 3 drop downs to filter the results. I have it setup to where 25 rows show on each page with a prev/next link.  After a search has been perform and when prev/next is clicked it goes back to show all results. I'm still trying to learn CF and I have been searching and trying how different things to get this to work. I'm looking for maybe a quick example or some direction to where I can learn how to do this part.  And I tried to shorten it.  Let me know if you need to see more code.

Here is some of the code...

```
<cfparam name="FORM.persType" type="string" default="%">
<cfquery name="r" datasource="#datasourcename#">
    SELECT *
    FROM Table
    WHERE
    Sector LIKE '#FORM.persType#'
    ORDER BY ID
</cfquery>

<!--- pagination setup --->
<cfset perpage = 25>
<cfparam name="url.start" default="1">
<cfif not isNumeric(url.start) or url.start lt 1 or url.start gt r.recordCount or  round(url.start) neq url.start>
    <cfset url.start = 1>
</cfif>

<cfset totalPages = ceiling(r.recordCount / perpage)>
<cfset thisPage = ceiling(url.start / perpage)>
<cfset thisPage = Int(start / 25) + 1>

Here's the output and pagination part...
<cfoutput query="r" startrow-"#url.start#" maxrows="#perpage#">
<tr>
    <td>#r.reqStatus#</td>
    <td>#r.lastName#</td>
    <td>#r.firstName#</td>
</tr>
</cfoutput>
</table>

<!--- Pagination --->
[
<cfif url.start gt 1>
<cfset link = cgi.script_name & "?start=" & (url.start - perpage)>
<cfoutput><a href="#link#">Previous Page</a></cfoutput>
<cfelse>
Previous Page
</cfif>
/
<cfif (url.start + perpage - 1) lt r.recordCount>
<cfset link = cgi.script_name & "?start=" & (url.start + perpage)>
<cfoutput><a href="#link#">Next Page</a></cfoutput>
<cfelse>
Next Page
</cfif>
]
```

Thank you for any help on this... :)

Comment: Ok Catherine...I'm looking a your new code base now.  Thank you for making a new question and providing your code (makes things easier). +1 to you.

Comment: Be sure to resolve and close out [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273041/coldfusion-and-pagination). Would not want S.O. to turn into one of those discussion-forum-graveyards with lots of unresolved questions without answers ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Catherine - this is the same question and same answer you asked before. With each of your pagination links you will need to pass the search params along. Each one is a new request and must be "refiltered".

Here's a clue for you to get you started:

At the top where you are doing your LIKE query alter your code to the following:

```
<cfparam name="FORM.persType" type="string" default="%">
<cfif structkeyexists(url,'persType')>
    <cfset FORM.perstype = url.persType/>
</cfif>
```

This will allow you to submit EITHER a "form" element OR a "url" element - they are treated as separate scopes in CF.

Then, in your pagination section alter your pagination links to the following:

```
<cfset link = cgi.script_name & "?start=" & (url.start - perpage) & "&persType=" & FORM.perstype/>
```

Make sure and do this for *each* of the links that represent pagination.

When completed you will be passing whatever the user has chosen for "persType" along with each pagination link - which will allow your query to rerun successfully and filter.

One more note - in your description you said you are filtering by *three* dropdowns. Each dropdown will be as separate variable that will need to be "passed along" like the pattern above. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! This is what I needed.  Now to just work on getting the other DDLs to work. :)  Thank you again!

Comment: You are welcome - glad we could help. You are on your way! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well for posterity. Here was my answer... :( (I got busy with work)

It provides:

- new parameter sets
- a new baseURL variable
- a form that allows for filtering (based on a table I had locally)

So this is just food for thought in a complete system. Again for posterity since you marked another answer as the solution...

```
<cfparam name="url.pageNum" default="1">
<cfparam name="url.isDraft" default="-1">
<cfparam name="url.showNav" default="-1"> 

<cfquery name="q" datasource="#application.dsn#">
SELECT * 
FROM table  <!--- you may need more than just a simple select.--->
WHERE 1=1
<cfif url.isDraft eq 0>
AND isDraft = 0
</cfif>
<cfif url.showNav eq 0>
AND showNav = 0
</cfif>                   
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>
<form action="" method="get">
    <lable>Filter Pages that are still being drafted</lable>
    <select name="isDraft">
        <option value="-1">Pick One</option>
        <option value="1" <cfif url.isDraft eq 1>selected</cfif>>Yes</option>
        <option value="0" <cfif url.isDraft eq 0>selected</cfif>>No</option>
    </select>
    <label>Filter Pages that Should or should not show up in nagivation</label>
    <select name="showNav">
        <option value="-1">Pick One</option>
        <option value="1" <cfif url.showNav eq 1>selected</cfif>>Yes</option>
        <option value="0" <cfif url.showNav eq 0>selected</cfif>>No</option>
    </select>      
    <input type="submit" name="" value="submit">
</form><br>
</cfoutput>

<cfset maxRows=10>
<cfset startRow=min( ( pageNum-1 ) * maxRows+1, max( q.recordCount,1 ) )>
<cfset endRow=min( startRow + maxRows-1, q.recordCount )>
<cfset totalPages=ceiling( q.recordCount/maxRows )>

<!--- PaginationBaseUrl will change --->

<cfif url.isDraft eq 1 OR url.showNav eq 0>
    <cfset setBaseLink='./?isDraft='&url.isDraft&'&showNav='&url.showNav&'&'>
<cfelse>
    <cfset setBaseLink='./?'>
</cfif> 

<cfset loopercount = round( q.recordCount/10 )>

<cfoutput>
    <cfloop from="1" to="#looperCount#" index="i">
            <a href="#setBaseLink#pageNum=#i#">#i#</a>
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput> 

<br><br>

<cfoutput
    query="q" 
    startrow="#startRow#"
    maxrows="#maxRows#">

    #id#<br>

</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Thank you Frank I will definitely try this one out too. I like having options. :) +1

Comment: I have a quick question based of this...not sure if this is an easy fix or not but when I do the search the URL stays the same and I can't perform another search.  Is there a way to kill the first search or refresh the page so multiple searches can be done?

Comment: @CatherineL I added some outs for you.  Note that cfparams at the top now are set to -1 and in the form fields there is additional options set.  The options are 'pick one' the value of those are set to '-1'. You'll see your pagination fix itself when you click back to 'pick one'...I think this will give you something additional to work with.